# Entity Framework Core 3.1.2 related data not returned with .Include()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-core-3.1

My 2 entities have a simple one-to-many i.e. parent child relationship.

```
    public class Itinerary {
        public Itinerary() {
            CodeHours=new List<CodeHours>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateWorked { get; set; }
        public String EnteredBy { get; set; }
        public List<CodeHours> CodeHours { get; set; }
    }

public class CodeHours {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Code { get; set; }
        public float Hours { get; set; }
        public Itinerary Itinerary { get; set; }
        public int ItineraryId { get; set; }

    }

    public class DBContext : DbContext {
        public DbSet<Itinerary> Itineraries { get; set; }
}
```

I am retrieving `Itinerary` from its DbSet like this

```
            Itinerary itn = ctx.Itineraries.Where(i => i.FirstName == Model.FirstName
            && i.LastName == Model.LastName
             && i.DateWorked == row.Date
            ).Include(i => i.CodeHours)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

I get the correct `Itinerary` but its `CodeHours` is always empty. SQL Server Profiler indicates that `CodeHours` table is never included in the query curiously I see 2 separate `select` statements being issued to SQL Server even though I have only 1 query against the DbSet in my code.

Adding `CodeHours` DbSet to my `DbContext` makes no difference.

The app is ASP.NET MVC 5. A similar example from an EF Core 3 course works but it is a Console App and not ASP.NET MVC

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You initialize `Itinerary.CodeHours`, which is OK, but do you happen to initialize `CodeHours .Itinerary` too?

Answer (score 0):

Not certain it's the cause of you're problem, but in your `Itinerary` class the type `CodeHours` is wrong. Should be:

```
public ICollection<CodeHours> CodeHours { get; set; }
```

It's okay to initialize it to a `List<CodeHours>` in the constructor for when you're creating new entities in memory, but when you fetch the from the DB, EF will put its own collection in there.

Comment: While it may be preferable to use `collection<T>`, using `List<T>` and initializing it is perfectly OK for EF.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the code working as-is by creating a new project from scratch and copying the relevant artifacts from the current non-working project. I think the project may have gotten corrupted when I initially added EF 6 but later on switched to using EF Core 3. Not sure if I removed EF 6 before adding EF Core 3.